# How to create private URL for cloudpages in Dev MC org?

Tags: marketing-cloud, url, cloudpage

I had dev MC org and was planned to create domain URL for my cloud pages but it will take me to create a case/support to salesforce people, any other to create that, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about something like this:
[image]

You will need to have a SAP setup on your org and tell SF which domain you bought or just buy it with them.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeremy. Actually, I cant able to see those URL "Web -domain" option. Its simply take to SF case or support service. We can't simply enter my domain & validate and use it. I need to take that sf mandatory!